# bind two data models to one model in mvc

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm creating MVC 5 application, in this application I'm joining multiple data table using one var model and bind that values to "DiscussionPreview_Model" model to list down data

this is controller class

```
   public ActionResult Discussion_Preview()
    {

        int Discussion_ID = 1;


        var discussion_preview = (from d in db.AB_Discussion
                                  where d.Discussion_ID == Discussion_ID
                                  join dc in db.AB_DiscussionComments on d.Discussion_ID equals dc.Discussion_ID
                                  join user_discussion in db.AspNetUsers on d.CreatedBy equals user_discussion.Id
                                  join user_comments in db.AspNetUsers on dc.CreatedBy equals user_comments.Id

                                  select new DiscussionPreview_Model
                                  {
                                      Disussion_ID = d.Discussion_ID,
                                      Discussion_CreateDate = d.CreatedDate,
                                      Discussion_CreateBy = user_discussion.UserName,
                                      Discussion_Title = d.Discussion_Name,
                                      Discussion_Description = d.Discription,
                                      Comment_ID = dc.Comment_ID,
                                      Comment_Description = dc.Comment_Discription,
                                      Comment_CreateDate = dc.CreatedDate,
                                      Comment_CreateBy = user_comments.UserName

                                  });


            return View(discussion_preview);
    }
```

this is my "DiscussionPreview_Model" model class

```
   public class DiscussionPreview_Model
    {

        DiscussionVM model1;
        CommentVM model2;

    }


    public partial class DiscussionVM
    {
        public int Disussion_ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Discussion_CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string Discussion_CreateBy { get; set; }
        public string Discussion_Title { get; set; }
        public string Discussion_Description { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<CommentVM> Comments { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class CommentVM
    {
        public int Comment_ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Comment_CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string Comment_CreateBy { get; set; }
        public string Comment_Description { get; set; }
    }
```

This is View Page

```
 @model IEnumerable<prjkt.Models.DiscussionPreview_Model>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Discussion_Preview";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@foreach (var discussion in Model.DiscussionVM)
{

<h3>>@discussion.Discussion_Title</h3>

<div>@discussion.Discussion_Description</div>
<div>@discussion.Discussion_CreateDate</div>
}

@foreach (var item in Model.CommentVM)
{

    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>


        <h4>Comments</h4>
        <div class="display-field">@item.Comment_Description</div>
        <div class="display-field">@item.Comment_CreateBy : @item.Comment_CreateDate </div>

    </fieldset>
}
```

but this is not working properly, I tried to overcome this problem in many ways

Really appreciate can  suggest a strong linq query approach

Comment: Did you not read my comments on your last question? `DiscussionVM` already contains a property for its comments. You need to initialize one `DiscussionVM`, populate its general properties (`Name`, `Description` etc) from the `AB_Discussion` table, then populate its collection of comments from the `AB_DiscussionComments` table.

Comment: What do you mean by not working properly ? Can you tell me what exact issue you are facing ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I cannot understand actually, what you meant, hope this is my lack of knowledge , really appreciate if you can show me example

Comment: @KaushikThanki  `DiscussionPreview_Model' does not contain a definition for 'Comment_ID,...`

Comment: I have already asked you to update the DotNetFiddle from you last question to show the models associated with `DiscussionVM` and `AB_DiscussionComments`!

Comment: @StephenMuecke here I included all the models associate within each other https://dotnetfiddle.net/A6acQM

Comment: @Chathz, I'll have a look at bit later, but start with `var discussion = db.db.AB_Discussion.Where(d => d.Discussion_ID == Discussion_ID).FirstOrDefault(); and populate the `Title`, `Description` etc properties of the view model. Then `var comments = db.AB_DiscussionComments.Where(c => c.Discussion_ID == Discussion_ID);` and use that to populate the `Comments` property (break it down into steps until you understand what your doing)

Comment: how to populate discussion view model properties with comment view model properties ?

Comment: `model.Comments = comments.Select(c => new CommentVM(){ Comment_ID = c.Comment_ID, Comment_Description = c.Comment_Description , ....etc};`

Comment: I have updated the [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kTNLJN) which will hopefully give you a better understanding

Comment: thanks lot for your continues assistance, because of your help its working fine , but I'm trying to fetch username by UserID I try to get Discussion User username and Comment user username

Comment: `Discussion_CreateBy = User.Identity.GetUserName(discussion.CreatedBy),` this is not working

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried this code to get username to catch Discussion username `Discussion_CreateBy = db.AspNetUsers.Find(discussion.CreatedBy).UserName` and it works then I use `Comment_CreateBy = db.AspNetUsers.Find(c.CreatedBy).UserName,` to catch comment usrname this is not working getting error http://s13.postimg.org/q0ixkygtj/error.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work here:

```
@foreach (var discussion in Model.DiscussionVM)
```

because Model.DiscussionVM is not an IEnumerable<>

Try enumerating Model and accessing .DiscussionVM of reach item in that collection

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<h3>@item.DiscussionVM.Discussion_Title</h3>

<div>@item.DiscussionVM.Discussion_Description</div>
<div>@item.DiscussionVM.Discussion_CreateDate</div>
}
```

Comment: Actually I have problem in Controller too ,